# Brown spots with yellow on cucumber and tomato plants

Tags: tomatoes, leaves, cucumbers

[image][image][image]Leaves of some my Cucumber and tomatoes plants are browning with yellow frames. also some of the stems of tomato plants appear to have a dark brown rust on them.  Is this a fungus?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Can't say with certainty without more close-up pictures and info. But, I'm going with Black Spot at this time, because both your tomato AND cucumber are affected. If that is the case, treat it very soon, or you won't have any viable fruit.

It could also be two different issues for the different plants (Black Speck, Canker, etc.), but that is less likely. If you update your post, I could help more.

In the meantime, here's a link to get you started.
http://vegetablemdonline.ppath.cornell.edu/DiagnosticKeys/TomLeaf/TomLeafKey.html

Comment: Certainly not an answer - but could a small part of the problem be lack of water ? (Possibly causing stress allowing for other factors?)  If you look at the pots, they look pretty dry to me - but I know looks can be deceiving.